# gensim save load model deprecation warning

Tags: gensim

I get the following deprecation warning when saving/loading a gensim word embedding:

```
model.save("mymodel.model")

/home/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:398: 
UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. 
See the migration notes for details:
```

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function

```
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' % _MIGRATION_NOTES_URL
```

I don't understand what to do following the notes on the page.
So, **how should I save and open my models instead?**

I use python 3.7 , gensim 3.7.3. and smart_open 1.8.4. I think I did not get the warning when using gensim 3.7.1. and python 3.5. smart_open should have been 1.8.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ignore most "deprecation warnings", as they're just an advisory about underlying changes that for now still work, but there's a new preferred way to do things that may be required in the future.

In this case, the warning is about a function inside the `smart_open` package that the `gensim` package is using. That is, it's **not** the `.save()` you are calling that's deprecated, but something inside `.save()`. The `gensim` authors will eventually update `.save()` to use the newly-preferred variant of what `smart_open` offers.

You can just keep using `.save()`, ignoring the message as long as things still work for you – unless you'd like to contribute the fix to `.save()` to remove the warning to `gensim`. (It may, however, have already been fixed in the development code, to become available in the next `gensim` release.)