# save gensim doc2vec trained model on google colab

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, gensim, sentiment-analysis, doc2vec

I am training text data using gensim doc2vec model on google colab repository GPU runtime, and want to save trained model in test.d2v file. following is code snippet

```
T = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(data['info'])]
model = Doc2Vec(T,alpha=.025, min_alpha=.025, min_count=1)
model.save('test.d2v')
```

Following error is generated in colab notebook.

** /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:253: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' % _MIGRATION_NOTES_URL

Comment: There is already a question on stackoverflow on that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456051/gensim-save-load-model-deprecation-warning

Answer (score 0):

A warning isn't necessarily an error, especially one that's just mentioning a 'deprecation'. Does your save file work? If so, it's safe to ignore this warning. See a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469545/130288) for more details.